# What application permissions are required to create a user in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, active-directory

I'm working on a simple Python application to automate creating/deleting users from our Azure instance on hiring/firing. I was able to get my script to create/delete test users using the `azure.graphrbac` library, but it required an admin user's sign-in credentials in the script which we're obviously not going to do long-term. I managed to get an app created and authenticated with `azure.common.credentials.ServicePrincipalCredentials` and connected successfully to our tenant with the proper settings, but I keep getting the below error every time I try to create a user. I have the below permissions (`Directory.ReadWrite.All`, `User.EnableDisableAccount.All`, and `User.ReadWrite.All`) applied to the application, what am I missing?

```
azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error.GraphErrorException: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

[image: permissions for Azure application]